# P CHANNEL MOSFET gate directly GPIO

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, switching

I'm currently using this circuit to control my load from MCU logic HIGH

[image: It works great, after self reflexion] why just not do like this ?

[image: What is the difference from the first] circuit ? It's safe for my MCU ?
I use NDP6020P is a Vgs(th) max -1V my VCC is 3.7V.

I know in the last circuit when MCU is LOW my load is "ON" instead the first circuit "LOW" = "OFF"

Regards

Comment: Depending on the gate capacitance and resistance of the FET, and the current capability of your MCU, you might need a gate resistor.

Comment: Input capacitance is 1590pF for NDP6020P and the current of my MCU is about 40mA ( absolute rating ) from GPIO.

Comment: The second schematic is **wrong**, you're shorting the supply across your load. The PMOS should be **in series** with the load and the VDD side. Just put a 1 kohm resistor in series with the gate to limit the gate charge/discharge current. That 40 mA current is not really an issue anyway as that current is just a short pulse. If it was a DC current flowing all day then it would be but here it is not. Also note that the 2nd schematic (but drawn correctly) will only work if the load supply is **the same** as the MCU supply. So: MCU at 5 V, load at 12 V => NO GO. Then use schematic 1.

Comment: @kiki67100: normally the source of a P-channel MOSFET is at the high side and the drain at the low side. It's the other way in your circuits. Often MOSFETs have integrated protection diodes going from drain to source (@ P-channel) or from source to drain (@ N-channel). That would mean in your case that that Diode is always ON. I guess that's not what you want and I doubt that the first circuit "works great" (if it is really the way you have drawn it).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't bothered to fix the mosfet from being upside down. This basically wastes people's time.

Comment: @Andyaka i just change the upside down mosfet in two circuit.

Answer (score 5):

You can drive an mosfet directly from the GPIO things. But you need to make sure it will work:

- The Vgs (V gate-source) threshold is when the mosfet turns on. The GPIO voltage should be able to get above this. Generally a mosfet that does this is called a logic level mosfet.
- The gate capacitance should not exceed the drive capabilities of the GPIO.
  This is easily solved by simply adding a resistor of ~100 ohm.
- The switch-on time meets your requirements. This might be slower than with a gate driver, and can cause extras losses in the mosfet when switching high currents.

This is for an N-channel. That is easy.
There are extra difficulties with a P-channel. Since the voltage to turn the P-channel off should not exceed the maximum level of the GPIO. This will typically be a maximum of 5V on five volt tolerant IO.
Meaning switching a p-fet directly on GPIO is not possible when switching more than 5V.

In case of your NDP6020P, the Vgs(th) graph looks like this:
[image: NDP6020P Vgs]

When Vgs is < 1 Volt, the fet is not conducting. The pullup to Vcc will do this.
When Vgs is > 2 Volt, the fet is conducting. Shorting gate to ground will do this.
The absolute gate voltage may not exceed the maximum GPIO voltage.

Typical circuit, including MCU internals:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNCkqs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you see. The 5V, or switched load voltage, may never exceed Vcc/Vdd of the MCU!

Comment: The Vgs(th) max is -1v, Vgs is -3.7v when i "turn on" i think is good enough. The Gate charge is 35nC that said until the gate capacitance is no charged have high current flow trough gpio/gate ? The gate mosfet has resistance ?

Comment: @kiki67100 You're worrying about the wrong things, Gate charge and gate series resistance: largely **irrelvant**. What is important: MCU supply voltage, load supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jeroen3 is see on the datasheet the "Gate-Source Voltage - Continuous" maximum is +/-8v my VCC is 3.7 and my GPIO HIGH is about 3.7v. I think is good.

Comment: I watch again your schema. The GPIO voltage has voltage drop of D1 and my MOSFET gate will have Vgs = (VCC) - (D1 DROP). If a use only the GPIO to feed the gate my MOFSET will be not "fully off" (in linear region). With R1 I'm sure that the gate is the equal of VCC and will limit the current when my GPIO goes LOW. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A high side, p channel mosfet requires a gate voltage of V+ - a diode drop to turn off. If V+, of the voltage at the source is higher than the gpio voltage at the gate, it would never turn off. That is why a NPN inverter driver is used. It allows a gpio with a voltage much lower than V+ to drive a p channel fet.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. You see the @Jeroen3 circuit ? He bias the gate with VCC trough the R1 ? In this case it works ? If you see the comment I add my "analyze"

Comment: @Kiki do not depend or abuse the internal diode protection of a gpio. They are not meant for that. That may be okay for a hobbyist project but not for production

Comment: What do you mean about " abuse the internal diode protection"

Comment: Clamp diodes are there for accidental (static discharge) situations. They are not there for connecting a higher voltage than the pin is meant for @Kiki