# Driving a p-channel MOSFET with a n-channel MOSFET

Tags: arduino, mosfet, voltage-regulator, servo

I want to use a p-channel MOSFET to turn off and on the power to a 6 V l7806 voltage regulator that powers a 6 V servo. The reason is to save battery power.

The controller is a 5 V Arduino. It is my understanding that I cannot directly drive the MOSFET because it needs to be driven to the 6 V to shut off the p-channel MOSFET.

Can an n-channel MOSFET be used as the driver? If so, what would the circuit look like?

Answer (score 2):

I searched for examples before I posted this.  Then directly on this site I asked the question differently and found my answer.

[p-channel MOSFET switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353218/p-channel-mosfet-switch)

Was exactly what had searched for before and now found.

Comment: Yes, if you need a high-side switch where V+ is higher than your logic level, use an N-channel MOSFET to drive the gate of the P-channel MOSFET. You can also use an NPN transistor to drive the P-channel MOSFET. Low-current NPNs are really cheap, but you will potentially waste more power. This is what I do for a pulsed application.

Comment: The basic topology is correct. You could probably use much larger than 10 k resistors if you want.

Comment: How does the larger resistor help?

Comment: @rlgjr562 It will reduce the amount of current flowing through it when the N-channel is turned on. This really only matters if efficiency is important. Increasing that resistance will also cause the P-Channel to turn off slower, so be aware of that.